# php preg_replace: find links and add a #hash to it?

Tags: php, hash, preg-replace

i have the following structure...

`$output = '<li><a href="http://forum.example.org">Something</a></li>'`
Actually $output holds multiple list-items.

What's the best and easiest way to apply a #hash to each links href? as in...

`<li><a href="http://forum.example.org#something">Something</a></li>`

Any idea how to solve that?

edit: btw it should always be the same #hash not as you might think in this example above, the #something is equal to the name of the link. So it should be #something for each link.

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'add_hash'); /*Add #hash to wp_list_pages() function*/
function add_hash($output) {

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($output);

        $a_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

        foreach($a_tags as $a)
        {
            $value = $a->getAttribute('href');
            $a->setAttribute('href', $value . '#b');
        }

        $dom->saveHTML();

        return $output;
}
```

Comment: You should try to adapt the list generation code which inserts the #hashes rather than modifying the concatenated result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str); // Change to input variable

$a_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($a_tags as $a)
{
    $value = $a->getAttribute('href');
    $a->setAttribute('href', $value . '#something');
}

// Get the new document with: $dom->saveHTML()
```

**Edit:**

In your above code, you need to change:

```
        $dom->saveHTML();

        return $output;
}
```

To:

```
        return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work! when I try to  `echo $value;` inside of the foreach loop it works fine, however when I try `echo $a;` the rest of the page doesn't get output. my console tells me `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::setAttribute()`

Comment: @mathiregister: Can you edit your question with the exact code you tried?

Comment: did edit my post. If I don't echo anything inside the loop like in the edit in my question everything gets output correctly, but without a #hash.

Comment: Perfect. I kindof tried that, but... whatever. Works fine now. Thank you for the awesome solution.